# Match two columns from two dataframes and provide different column

Tags: r

I want to match two dataframes of different dimensions (df1 & df2) based on the "Index" column. Then, add two columns from df2 (shift & shiftdate) to df1 based on the match. But I have multiple rules I need to follow.

```
df1 <- data.frame("Index" = c("Adams10-1", "Adams10-1", "Adams10-2", "Adams10-2", "Ball10-1", "Ball10-2", "Cash10-1", "Cash10-2", "David10-1", "David10-2"),
                    "CaseDate" = c("2005-10-01", "2005-10-01", "2005-10-02", "2005-10-02", "2005-10-01", "2005-10-02", "2005-10-01", "2005-10-02", "2005-10-01", "2005-10-02"),
                    "Type" = c("heart", "local", "knee", "nose", "heart", "foot", "shin", "foot", "spine", "delivery"),
                  "StartTime" = c(1640, 1755, 0112, 0300, 2145, 0233, 2123, 0326, 858, 1024))

df2 <- data.frame("Index" = c("Adams10-1", "Adams10-1", "Ball10-1", "Cash10-1", "David10-1", "David10-1", "David10-3"),
                     "ShiftDate" = c("2005-10-01", "2005-10-01", "2005-10-01", "2005-10-01", "2005-10-01", "2005-10-01", "2005-10-03"),
                  "Shift" = c("OB", "CV", "Night", "Super", "OB", "Day", "OB"),
                  "Multiple" = c("yes", "yes", "no", "no", "yes", "yes", "no"))
```

Rules:

1. If there is a match between df1$Index and df2$Index AND:

   - if df2$Multiple == "no", then add df2$Shift and df2$ShiftDate to df1
   - if df2$Multiple == "yes" , then give NA (UNLESS df1$Type == "heart" & df2$Shift == "CV" (in this instance, add the CV shift and shiftdate from df2 to df1))
2. If no match between df1$Index and df2$Index, give NA

   - UNLESS df1$StartTime >0000 and <0700 (in this instance, add df2$shift and df2$shiftdate from df2$shiftdate that is one day before df1$CaseDate)
   - UNLESS df1$Type == "delivery" & df2$Shift = "OB" (in this instance, add df2$shift and df2$shiftdate from df2$shiftdate that is one day after df1$CaseDate)

I want to get the results below.

```
df3 <- data.frame("Index" = c("Adams10-1", "Adams10-1", "Adams10-2", "Adams10-2", "Ball10-1", "Ball10-2", "Cash10-1", "Cash10-2", "David10-1", "David10-2"),
                     "CaseDate" = c("2005-10-01", "2005-10-01", "2005-10-02", "2005-10-02", "2005-10-01", "2005-10-02", "2005-10-01", "2005-10-02", "2005-10-01", "2005-10-02"),
                     "Type" = c("heart", "local", "knee", "nose", "heart", "foot", "shin", "foot", "spine", "delivery"),
                     "StartTime" = c(1640, 1755, 0112, 0300, 2145, 0233, 2123, 0326, 858, 1024),
                     "Shift" = c("CV", NA, NA, NA, "Night", "Night", "Super", "Super", NA, "OB"),
                      "ShiftDate" = c("2005-10-01", NA, NA, NA, "2005-10-01", "2005-10-01", "2005-10-01", "2005-10-01", NA, "2005-10-03"))
```

Even if I can't do this based on all of these rules, just getting help with matching will be helpful. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'd think you could easily start with `merge(df1,df2,all=TRUE)` and then do straight-forward column-calculation from there.

Comment: If ``df1`` has two matches in ``df2``, and one has ``Multiple = "yes"`` and the other has ``Multiple = "no"``, which subpart of rule 1 applies?  The example ``df3`` suggests that it's the second part, and ``df1`` gets nothing from the matching non-multiple record in ``df2``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to make some assumptions here, based on the structure of `df1` and `df2` and the contents of the target dataset provided in the question.

- `Index` is just the combination of a person identifier (here, a name) and the shift or case date.  So we really want to join on person and date.
- `Multiple` in `df1` just identifies whether the person has multiple shifts in one day.  (I'm assuming the `no` for the first `David10-1` record is a typo.)  So Rule 1 is really about whether the person has multiple shifts in one day.

If those two are correct, we can do the following.  This code is pretty redundant in several places; it could be tightened up a lot.  But it shows the logic of the rules very explicitly.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# First, let's do make two changes: (1) convert the dates to real dates, and
# (2) replace Index with Name.
df1 = df1 %>%
  mutate(CaseDate = ymd(CaseDate),
         Name = gsub("[^A-Za-z]", "", Index)) %>%
  select(Name, CaseDate, Type, StartTime)
df2 = df2 %>%
  mutate(ShiftDate = ymd(ShiftDate),
         Name = gsub("[^A-Za-z]", "", Index)) %>%
  select(Name, ShiftDate, Shift)

# Start with df1.
df3 = df1 %>%
  # Bring in matching records in df2.  Filter df2 to records that are either
  # (1) the only record for that person, or (2) CV shifts.
  left_join(df2 %>%
              group_by(Name, ShiftDate) %>%
              mutate(num.shifts = n()) %>%
              filter(num.shifts == 1 | Shift == "CV"),
            by = c("Name", "CaseDate" = "ShiftDate")) %>%
  # We want to keep Shift and ShiftDate for records from df2 that are either
  # (1) the only record for that person, or (2) CV shifts that join to a
  # "heart" type in df1.
  mutate(Shift = case_when(num.shifts == 1 ~ Shift,
                           Type == "heart" & Shift == "CV" ~ Shift,
                           T ~ NA_character_),
         ShiftDate = case_when(num.shifts == 1 ~ CaseDate,
                               Type == "heart" & Shift == "CV" ~ CaseDate)) %>%
  select(Name, CaseDate, Type, StartTime, Shift, ShiftDate) %>%
  # Bring in records in df2 that match on person and whose shift date is the
  # day before the case date.
  left_join(df2 %>%
              group_by(Name, ShiftDate) %>%
              filter(n() == 1) %>%
              mutate(ShiftDateOneDayLater = ShiftDate + 1),
            by = c("Name", "CaseDate" = "ShiftDateOneDayLater")) %>%
  # Keep Shift and ShiftDate only if StartTime is between 0000 and 0700.
  mutate(Shift = case_when(!is.na(Shift.x) ~ Shift.x,
                           StartTime > 0 & StartTime < 700 ~ Shift.y),
         ShiftDate = case_when(!is.na(ShiftDate.x) ~ ShiftDate.x,
                               StartTime > 0 & StartTime < 700 ~ ShiftDate.y)) %>%
  select(Name, CaseDate, Type, StartTime, Shift, ShiftDate) %>%
  # Bring in records in df2 that match on person and whose shift date is the
  # day after the case date.
  left_join(df2 %>%
              group_by(Name, ShiftDate) %>%
              filter(n() == 1) %>%
              mutate(ShiftDateOneDayBefore = ShiftDate - 1),
            by = c("Name", "CaseDate" = "ShiftDateOneDayBefore")) %>%
  # Keep Shift and ShiftDate only if this is a "delivery" case and an "OB"
  # shift.
  mutate(Shift = case_when(!is.na(Shift.x) ~ Shift.x,
                           Type == "delivery" & Shift.y == "OB" ~ Shift.y),
         ShiftDate = case_when(!is.na(Shift.x) ~ ShiftDate.x,
                               Type == "delivery" & Shift.y == "OB" ~ ShiftDate.y)) %>%
  select(Name, CaseDate, Type, StartTime, Shift, ShiftDate)
```

Comment: This works, thank you so much! Yes, you are correct about the assumptions and my error. I fixed it in the original post. I did get this error from your code: `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: must be type integer, not character` I changed `NA_character_` to `NA_integer_` and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: Aha, of course - I forgot to mention that I changed everything to factors (not strings) when I was testing things out.  So that makes sense.  Cheers!

Comment: Hi, I've run into an issue after refining some of my matching conditions. Could you please help correct my code here? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56298310/merge-two-dataframes-with-dplyrleft-join-and-multiple-conditions]